# Unable to change notification title in Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, vue-cli

I am now able to implement push notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging, and the push notifications themselves are delivered, but I am having trouble changing their content.

The default title is "This site has been updated in the background", but I changed it to any text.

- Environment

  - Vue CLI
  - TypeScript
- main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
  measurementId: "xxx"
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const app = createApp(App)
installElementPlus(app)

app
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .component('MqResponsive', Vue3Mq.MqResponsive)
  .mount('#app')

const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
const vapidKey = {
  vapidKey:
    "xxx",
};
// Messaging
getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'xxx' }).then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
    console.log("currentToken : ", currentToken);
    // ...
  } else {
    // Show permission request UI
    console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    // ...
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
  // ...
});
```

- firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { onBackgroundMessage } from "firebase/messaging/sw";
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
  measurementId: "xxx"
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
const vapidKey = {
  vapidKey:
    "xxx",
};

// Messaging
getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'xxx' }).then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
    console.log("currentToken : ", currentToken);
    // ...
  } else {
    // Show permission request UI
    console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    // ...
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
  // ...
});

onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
  // ...
});

onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);

  self.addEventListener('push', async function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
      self.registration.showNotification('title', {
        body: 'body'
      })
    );
  });
});
```

The image is localhost, but deploying to the web did not change the result.
I also tested on Firebase Messaging and downloaded as a PWA and again the results did not change.

What is the problem??

[image]

Thank you in advance!